# Angular Directive Syntax in HAML

Tags: angularjs, haml

I cannot get the syntax right - how do you add a directive to a haml template?

Let's say I have a directive called `my-directive'. I would like to put that into a haml template.

**Attempt 1:** Straight html syntax

`<my-directive></my-directive>`

Obviously, doesn't work.

**Attempt 2:** As a class

`.my-directive`

**Attempt 3:** Using ng syntax

`{:ng => 'my-directive' }`

**Attempt 4:** Using data

`{ :ng => { :data => "newDirective" } }`

**Attempt 5:** Using html/haml element

`%my-directive`

**Attempt 6:** Wrapping div with ng

`%div{ :ng => 'my-directive' }`

**Attempt 7:** Wrapping div with data

`%div{ :ng => { :data => "newDirective" } }`

None of these worked.

**Resources consulted:**

[Using AngularJS within Haml views of a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895551/using-angularjs-within-haml-views-of-a-rails-app)

[HAML/Angular tutorial](http://www.writelessdomore.co.uk/category/haml/)

[HAML Github Issues](https://github.com/haml/haml/issues)

[Reddit Question](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/28lfhs/angularjs_and_haml_what_ways_can_we_add_a/)

Comment: What is the final HTML you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there's not a way I can make it not work:

```
%my-directive

%span(ng-key="value")

%div{data: {ngKey: 'value', ng_foo: 'bar'}}

%div{ng: {foo: 'bar'}}
```

Output:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
<span ng-key='value'></span>
<div data-ng-foo='bar' data-ngKey='value'></div>
<div ng-foo='bar'></div>
```

(Used Haml 4.0.7)

Comment: Ok, I just goofed my angular code then.  Appreciate the response.